# After rendering picklist controls are not Selectable

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am using two tags `<h:selectOneMenu>` and `<p:pickList>.` I want to render `<p:pickList>` tag when an entry in the `<h:selectOneMenu>` is selected.

Earlier after page loading the add, add all other controls are visible as pickList controls but after rendering this pickList, these controls change to jsf buttons with no functionality of pickList.

Here is the snippet code(xhtml file):

```
<div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">#{texts['person.userrole']}
    </label>
    <h:selectOneMenu
        value="#{userroleDataActions.actualUserRole.rolename}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{userroleDataActions.roles}" />
        <f:ajax  listener="#{userroleSaveActions.rolelistener}"
            render="projects"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <p:messages styleClass="error" />
</div>


<p:pickList id="projects"
    value="#{userroleSaveActions.projectDualList}" var="projects"
    itemLabel="#{projects}" itemValue="#{projects}"
    converter="projectConverter" required="true" />
```

Comment: any info/errors in the clientside console? Network tab? server side? If not, please create an [mcve]

Comment: i have delete jquery libarys and it works. Because Primefaces has already jquery libarys included.

Comment: And that we could not see due to you **not** providing an [mcve], so next time please do